# Getting strange output from printf

Tags: windows-mobile

What causes StringCchPrintfW(buf, buflen, L"%f", double_var) to output "-1.#IO" in Windows Mobile? I am also getting "-1.#IND" sometimes. Documentation mentions "1.#INF" and "-1.#INF" where #INF means infinity, but there is no mention of "#IO" or "#IND".

Comment: `-1.#IO` means "not a number". `-1.#IND` means "indeterminate". You might want to check what is in double_var and who/what is setting its value.

Comment: The variable is the result of a series of calculations that determine a distance between two latitude/longtitude coordinates using sin/cos/acos and then dividing the distance by elapsed time to get velocity. It is the velocity value that is unprintable sometimes.

Comment: Turns out that the value being passed to acos() was sometimes greater than 1.0 which resulted in NAN (Not A Number).

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the first two parameters to the function. [StringCchPrintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647541%28VS.85%29.aspx) formats to a string which you need to provide rather than printing it.

Comment: Your response did not answer why the output from the function has #IO in it instead of a valid number